May sec-fetch-dest header be used to distinguish REST requests from other browser HTTP requests?
The actual problem - at server side we need to distinguish REST requests from other browser HTTP requests like image request, page request and etc. By saying "REST request" I mean a request made by JS utilities like XMLHTTPRequest or fetch; by saying "other browser requests" I mean requests generated when you open a webpage, a webpage loads images, sounds, video and etc.
So, when I encountered this problem I first started to look for some criteria that can help me reliably distinguish these kinds of requests and of course the first idea that came to me was headers - there must be some headers that are present on REST requests and absent on others (or vice versa or something else). A little investigation led me to understanding of the fact that my fetch requests has "Sec-Fetch-Dest" header set to "empty" and other browser generated requests has "Sec-Fetch-Dest" with other values. And since I found no exceptions for this rule I thought the problem is solved - on server side we just check if a request has "sec-fetch-dest" header and it has explicit value of "empty", and if yes then it is REST request; if not then some other automatically generated request. But then I googled sec-fetch-dest and found not so much mentionings of sec-fetch-dest and instantly thought that my solution is not that elegant or adequate as I thought, and maybe there is something else that people do to distinguish REST requests from generic requests.
Hence the question - is existence of "sec-fetch-dest: empty" header is a reliable criteria to tell REST requests from generic requests for a HTTPS web app?  If not then what are the other options?
Thanks in advance!
PS: it may look like this old question is the same as mine - Sec-Fetch-Dest request header attribute to determine if it is a page, but it actually not the same
No idea which tags should this question have, edit please

MDN says empty "is used for destinations that do not have their own value. For example: fetch(), navigator.sendBeacon(), EventSource, XMLHttpRequest, WebSocket, etc." If you are only talking about requests made by you / your application, where you know that you will use those methods to make such requests only, suppose it might suffice. If something else might for example use fetch to request an image in the background ... not sure, would you want to consider this a "REST request" then, or not?

@C3roe, yeah, you're right, the word "REST" does not have much sense here, I use it just to disinguish explicit JS requests from automatic browser requests. So, yes, explicit image request would be a REST request too

Since nobody joined the conversation and thus there are no objections I think it's ok to say that in secured web apps a criteria of an HTTP request having "sec-fetch-dest" header set to "empty" may be reliably used to distinguish REST requests from other browser generated HTTP requests
